# How to add a list item in the middle of a list with JQuery

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

I have a list with two items, I want to add additional items after the first item when the content is loaded. How is this done? I can add items, but they only show up on the end of the list. Do I have to call or use the list element array?

First I create the new list item (`<li>`) and then I populate the list item with the content. But I think I need to define the position of the list item before or while I add the li item.

```
if(x > 0){  
  $('<li></li>').attr('id','liAdult_'+x).appendTo($("ul:#ulAdultList"));
   //$("ul:#ulAdultList").add($('<li></li>').attr('id','liAdult_'+x)).after($('#liAdult_0'));
   $('<img/>').attr({'id':'imgAdultAvatar_'+x,'src':'./images/person_20x20.jpg','class':'imgAvatar','title':'The persons avatar','alt':'Avatar Adults'}).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
   $('<span></span>').attr({'id':'sAdultFirstName_'+x,'class':'sAdultLine'}).html(xData.adults[x].personFirstName).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
   $('<span></span>').attr({'id':'sAdultLastName_'+x,'class':'sAdultLine'}).html(xData.adults[x].personLastName).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));  
   $('<span></span>').attr({'id':'sAdultParent_'+x,'class':'sAdultLine'}).html(xData.adults[x].guardianRole).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
   $('<span></span>').attr({'id':'sAdultCellPhone_'+x,'class':'sAdultLine'}).html(xData.adults[x].personCellPhone).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
   $('<input/>').attr({'id':'personId_'+x,'type':'hidden'}).val(xData.adults[x].personId).appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
   $('<a></a>').attr({'id':'lnkAdultProfile_'+x,'href':'#','name':'lnkAdultProfile_'+x,'title':'Edit the adult profile'}).html('Profile').appendTo($('#liAdult_'+x));
}
```

Comment: Almost forgot, thanks for the replies, it helped me to solve the issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To add a new item after the first one:

```
$('li:nth-child(1)').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) which will add it to the end like you have:

```
$('<li></li>').attr('id','liAdult_'+x).appendTo($("ul:#ulAdultList"));
```

Use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to stick it at the location you want, like this:

```
$('<li></li>').attr('id','liAdult_'+x).insertAfter("#ulAdultList li:first");
```

This will insert it after the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) `<li></li>` in that `<ul>`.